# Handling collections of objects through a switch statement

Tags: c#, interface, polymorphism, switch-statement

I need to have a player equip an item as shown here:

`IEquiptable` is an interface.

and this method is in my in `player` class.

```
public void equip(IEquiptable equipable) 
    {
        switch (equipable.GetType())
        {
            case equipable is Weapons:
                this.weapon = equipable;
                break;

            case equipable is Shield:
                this.shield = equipable
                break;

                //etc etc..
        }
    }
```

I get an error that the switch experession must be a bool,char,string,integral, enum or corresponding nullable type.

I could handle it by having an equit method in each of my weapon/shield etc classes and pass over my `player` class as a parameter. But I feel this is slightly illogical as a player should equipt an item, not an item equip it's self on the player.

Comment: What's the type of `Player.weapon` and `Player.shield`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have an interface so why don't you make use of it?

```
public interface IEquipable
{
    void EquipOn( Player player );
}

public class Shield : IEquipable
{
    public void EquipOn( Player player )
    {
        player.shield = this;
    }
}

public class Weapons : IEquipable
{
    public void EquipOn( Player player )
    {
        player.weapon = this;
    }
}
```

and your code becomes

```
public void equip(IEquiptable equipable) 
{
   equipable.EquipOn( this ); 
}
```

In fact, you don't even need this method, as it has been reduced to merely forwarding its job to proper class. Everytime you have your `IEquipable` you just call its `EquipOn` method.

Comment: It's what I originally had planned to do, just it felt slightly illogical to have the item equip it's self on the player.

Comment: This is because instead of two interfaces, `IShield` and `IWeapon` you decided to have just one. Sonner or later you will have to violate the Interface Segregation Principle (if you put too much different responsibilities into `IEquipable`) or - if you don't - the interface won't be as usable as it should be. Try to separate these responsibilities and your original design where the `Player` class has overloaded methods to equip weapons and shields will again be valid.

Comment: My `Weapon` and `Shield` both extend a base abstract class of `Item` There is unique functionality in both `Weapon` and `Shield` class, but I knew that both of these items can be equipted by the player in a slightly different way, which I thought perfect chance for an interface. Just I find it difficult to know where to place the logic from he interface.

Comment: I notice a lot of examples for interfaces use vehicle examples: `Car implements IDriveable` But it's a person who drives the car, surely the method `Drive` should be in a Human/Player/Driver or whatever class

Answer (score 1):

```
public void equip(IEquiptable equipable) 
{
   var type = equipable.GetType();
   if(type is Weapons)
   {
    this.weapon = equipable;
    return;
   }
   if(type is Shield)
   {
     this.shield = equipable;
     return;
   }
   //etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the values of *cases* must be constants, the conventional solution would be to create an *enum* ..

```
public enum EquippableTypes {
    Weapons,
    Shield,
    Antenna,
    Underwear
}

public partial class Player {
    public void Equip(IEquippable equippable) {
        switch(equippable.Type) {
            case EquippableTypes.Weapons:
                this.weapon=equippable;
                break;

            case EquippableTypes.Shield:
                this.shield=equippable;
                break;

            case EquippableTypes.Antenna:
                this.antenna=equippable;
                break;

            case EquippableTypes.Underwear:
                this.underwear=equippable;
                break;

            // ... 
        }
    }

    IEquippable weapon, shield, antenna, underwear;
}
```

So your equippable interface/classes would look like that ..

```
public partial interface IEquippable {
    EquippableTypes Type {
        get;
    }
}

public partial class Weapons: IEquippable {
    public EquippableTypes Type {
        get {
            return EquippableTypes.Weapons;
        }
    }
}

public partial class Shield: IEquippable {
    public EquippableTypes Type {
        get {
            return EquippableTypes.Shield;
        }
    }
}

public partial class Antenna: IEquippable {
    public EquippableTypes Type {
        get {
            return EquippableTypes.Antenna;
        }
    }
}

public partial class Underwear: IEquippable {
    public EquippableTypes Type {
        get {
            return EquippableTypes.Underwear;
        }
    }
}
```